# Which MTurk parameter to use to mention no. of workers per HIT?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am creating a HIT with external question (i.e. hosting the questions on my own website). I want to mention the maximum no. of workers that can take the HIT test.

When I used MaxAssignments=50 for this purpose (to mention no. of distinct workers I want to complete the created HIT), I see "Assignments requested = 1" in requester page. But I wanted this value to be 50.

Maybe I am using a wrong parameter? Which parameter I should use to achieve this?

Comment: Please show the code you used to create the HIT and say how you're accessing MTurk (i.e., what language, SDK, etc.).

Comment: I am using PHP to send and get results (in XML form) from amazon mechanical turk site.